# brew install python installs python2

Tags: python, nltk, homebrew

I have 3 versions of python installed on my Mac. 2 of them are through brew i.e. python2 and python3 while the native version is python. the problem is when I put `brew install python` it installs python2 and not python. (By saying python means the version which runs on putting that command in terminal). What should I do so that if I type python my brew installed python launches.**I have my path variables set correctly and the brew installation path is ahead than that of the usr/bin** The problem I am encountering is that I have nltk installed through pip, pip2 and pip3 and when I `import nltk` in python2 and python3 there is no problem but when I do that in python it show no module found.

Comment: i'm confused. `python` typically is `python2`. At least on OS X and Ubuntu

Comment: for what it's worth, using virtual environments should get you past this headache. Then it likely won't matter which one you're running.

Comment: @TinyTheBrontosaurus I am confused too because those are giving me different results. what brew installed, I am able to invoke that only by python2 and not python. See the answer and my comment on that

Comment: @TinyTheBrontosaurus using virtualenv is not solving my problem as I make a virtualenv, type pip install nltk but still in python shell import nltk gives me no modules is present while it runs fine in python2. The final problem over here is that my python and python2 are not same

Answer (score 1):

Try `which python` in a terminal to see which python will run. Then you know and can act accordingly to fix it.

`ls -lsa $(which python)` will let you see if it is a symlink to another location or a real executable. if a Symlink you can see where it points to and so you can follow the breadcrumbs to the final binary used.

if you run `python` from a terminal and in the python REPL do the following

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

you can see to which site-packages locations are pointed.

Other than that you of course have the option to use virtual environments to set up your version of python

if you really want python2 to be the default python command you can add a symlink to your ~/bin folder (create it if it does not exist)

```
mkdir ~/bin
cd ~/bin
ln -s $(which python2) python
chmod +x python
```

and make sure that `export PATH=~/bin:$PATH` is added at the back of your `.bashrc` or `.profile` or `.zshrc` file

Now start a new terminal session and try out `python` again it should point to brews version

Hope that helps

Comment: both the commands say there is only version of python is installed and that is the native version of python shipped with osx. what brew installed is called python2 not python. how do I fix this?

Comment: Adjusted my answer hope it is what you are looking for

Comment: Dude it still points to `usr/bin/python` Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 15 2017, 17:16:57) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. while `which python2` says `/Users/<myusername>/homebrew/bin/python2`

Comment: have you started a NEW terminal shell after following the instructions? I have just tested it on my mac and there is no trouble.  ( $ python
Python 2.7.14 (default, Sep 25 2017, 09:54:19)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>)

Comment: I opened a new tab of my terminal and I did it using  a new window too

Comment: The export must be at the end of your startup script as you have to be sure that `~/bin` is at the beginning of your PATH. The instructions above should be enough to get you going. Follow them :-)

Comment: and of course `/usr/bin/python` still exists because we did not throw it away and you don't want to as it is part of macOs. you only added your bin folder before the /usr/bin folder in your path making your python command the one found first...